# 2d integer array for the purpose of returning unique collection in ascending order for each dimensions

Tags: java, netbeans

Create a method uniqueValue that return a 2d integer array collection. The method  accepts a 2d integer array for the purpose of returning unique collection in ascending order for each dimensions...

Example:

input:

```
int [][] myArray = {
        { 5, 32, 8, 45, 9, 10, 1, 2, 45, 6, 1, 8 },
        { 4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2 }
};
```

output:

```
int[][] newArray = {
        { 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 32, 45 },
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}

};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Keep in mind that we are not here to do your homework for you. We can help you solve any issues you might be facing when you attempt to do it yourself, however, but to do so we need you to provide a [mre] and clearly explain what problems you are having.

Comment: You have 2 arrays of 1d integers. I guess your textbook rather requires something like {[5,1], [32,2], ...}

Comment: my professor gave that problem, and i cant understand on how to do that codes. please help me

Comment: It looks like he wants you to sort each array, removing duplicates.

Comment: Should the result be a 2D array _or_ collection of arrays _or_ array_ of collections?  Are you allowed to use existing Java facilities for sorting like `Arrays.sort / Collections.sort`?  Do unique values need to be provided not per _dimension_ but _per row_ ?

Comment: my professor said ' The numbers are ascending and will previously return into output '

Comment: were not allowed to use that arra.sort, just a simple codes like for loop nested loop and if else like that

Comment: If you really don't want to use your own mind, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses Java Stream API:

```java
static int[][] sortAndRemoveDuplicates(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)  // Stream of int[]
                 .map(row ->   // process each row
                     IntStream.range(0, row.length)  // analog of for loop, stream of indexes
                              .map(i -> row[i])      // convert to stream of int elements
                              .sorted()              // sort in ascending order by default
                              .distinct()            // remove duplicates
                              .toArray()             // build int[] array
                 )
                 .toArray(int[][]::new);  // build result 2D array
}
```

Test:

```java
int[][] myArray = {
    {5, 32, 8, 45, 9,10 ,1 ,2 , 45, 6, 1, 8},
    {4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2}
};

int[][] newArray = sortAndRemoveDuplicates(myArray);
Arrays.stream(newArray)
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 32, 45]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

java provides a class by name of `Arrays` which gives you lots of options for example I used to sort array and then remove the duplicates:

```
int[][] myArray = { { 5, 32, 8, 45, 9, 10, 1, 2, 45, 6, 1, 8 }, { 4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2 } };

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray[i]);
    myArray[i] = Arrays.stream(myArray[i]).distinct().toArray();
}

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[i]));
}
```